# How can I plot a paraboloid?

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis

How do I plot a function for a paraboloid? Im putting together surfaces to model lipstick. I need the paraboloid for the top part and then I'll be cutting the paraboloid at angle with another surface. But I can't seem to get a handle on how to plot a simple paraboloid function.

Comment: provide some code sample. Relevant examples you may find [here](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/EllipticParaboloid/)

Comment: thank you, sorry im new to mathematica

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! Do not forget to 1) Read the faq! 2) When you see good questions and answers, _vote them up by clicking the gray triangles_. 3) Also, please remember to _accept the answer_ that solves your problem, by *clicking the checkmark sign*!

Comment: Alright, Thank You! :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For fun:

```
RegionPlot3D[
 z <= -2 x^2 - 2 y^2 && z <= 8 x + y - 20,
 {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, {z, -100, 0},
 PlotPoints -> 150, Mesh -> None, 
 PlotStyle -> Directive[Darker@Red, Specularity[1]],
 Axes -> False, Boxed -> False
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: beautiful!!! is there a tutorial for this you link me to? i didnt want to copy and paste your work

Comment: You are welcome to use my code as you see fit. To work with it further, I'd suggest starting with the Mathematica docs, maybe the [Basic Plotting Tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/BasicPlotting.html) and moving up from there. This site is also an excellent source of solutions and snippets of useful code.

Answer (score 2):

```
Manipulate[
 Plot3D[c (s x^2/a + y^2/b), {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}],

 {{a, 1}, .1, 5},
 {{b, 1}, .1, 5},
 {{c, 1}, .1, 5},

 {{s, 1}, {1 -> "Elliptic", -1 -> "Hyperbolic"}}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 0):

The general paraboloid is given by $\dfrac{x^2}{a^2}+\dfrac{y^2}{b^2}=\dfrac{z}{c}$. You can generate the plot using `Plot3D`.

For example, if $f(x,y)=\dfrac{x^2}{4}+9y^2$, you can plot the function with

```
f[x_, y_] = x^2/4 + 9y^2
Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}]
```

You can refer to the documentation for various plotting and styling options.

[image]